# NextGEN Gallery Lightbox - Social Share URL Redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, wp-redirect, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am using NextGEN Gallery Pro - Lightbox's Social Share feature on my WordPress site which actually create and share a temporarily created url (first-url) on social media. Somehow the redirect doesn't work and generates a blank page when I visit the first-url. I am thinking to add a manual htaccess rewrite rule or preferably WordPress function to make this redirect possible.

How can I add such rewrite rule in `.htaccess` or a WordPress hook to redirect first-url to second-url?

Redirect first-url:

```
example.com/nextgen-share/121212/8989/full?uri=/landscape-photography/
```

to

second-url:

```
example.com/landscape-photography/#gallery/121212/8989
```

I've tried several manual `.htaccess` rewrite rules but no joy. Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: "Somehow the redirect doesn't work and generates a blank page" - What URL does it redirect to? Or does it not redirect at all?

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect at all and stays on first-url with a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following in `.htaccess` *before* the existing WordPress directives.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uri=(/[^&]+)
RewriteRule ^nextgen-share/(\d+/\d+)/full$ %1#gallery/$1 [QSD,NE,R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches against the URL-path, so you need the preceding `RewriteCond` directive in order to match the query string portion of the URL.

If the `/121212/8989/` part always consists of 6 digits and 4 digits then you can be more restrictive in the regex. ie. `(\d{6}/\d{4})`. Likewise, if the `uri` parameter value consists of a limited subset of characters - perhaps a single path segment - then again this can be made more restrictive.

`%1` is a backreference to the captured subpattern in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive, ie. the value of the `uri` URL parameter.

`$1` is a backreference to captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, eg. `121212/8989` in your example URL.

The `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required to prevent the `#` being URL encoded in the response (and being seen as part of the URL-path).

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the redirected URL, otherwise the query string from the requested URL is copied as-is onto the end of the *substitution*. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then you can append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* instead (essentially appending an empty query string).

This is a temporary (302) redirect.

> **UPDATE:** This will only work if 121212 but what if it's alpha-numeric (abc121212)

To allow a-z (lowercase) and digits then you would need to modify the `RewriteRule` pattern to `^nextgen-share/([0-9a-z]+/[0-9a-z]+)/full$`. If you need to allow uppercase letters as well then change `[0-9a-z]` to `[0-9a-zA-Z]`. You could also use the `\w` "word characters" shorthand character class here instead, which is the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` - note the additional `_` (underscore).

So, this becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uri=(/[^&]+)
RewriteRule ^nextgen-share/(\w+/\w+)/full$ %1#gallery/$1 [QSD,NE,R,L]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly... I've made the slash mandatory at the start of the `uri` parameter value, since this is required in order to construct a valid redirect. (Otherwise it will be reliant on the value of the `RewriteBase` directive.)

Comment: This will work if 121212 part is digits only but what if it's alpha-numeric (abc121212)? Does this also work if last part of the query string is /landscape-photography/sub--photography/ rather than just /landscape-photography/?

I am playing with the rewrite rules you've provided already but your inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to modify the regex to allow for letters - I've updated my answer. The current condition will already allow for `/landscape-photography/sub--photography/` - providing the value starts with a slash.

Comment: It started to redirect but also adds query string portion at the end of second-url (new url). Means `mywordpress_domain.com/landscape-photography/#gallery/121212/8989?uri=/landscape-photography/`

Comment: I've added `?` after `$1` and it removed `?uri=/landscape-photography/` from the new url. Thanks. Here is the final rewrite rule: `RewriteRule nextgen-share/([0-9a-zA-Z]+/[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/full$ %1#gallery/$1? [NE,R,L]`

Comment: Sorry, yes, you need to add the QSD flag to the Rewrite rule.

Comment: The `?` essentially appends an empty string, preventing the query string from the request being automatically appended. However, if you are on Apache 2.4+ then using the `QSD` flag is preferred. (I've updated my answer.)